# Fill in a form in a browser using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn how to fill in a form in a browser using javascript. However
I keep getting redirected to a blank page with only the inputted value.

For example on this site:

https://login.yahoo.com/config/login

I'm trying to fill in the box with "username" however when I enter:

"javascript: document.getElementById('login-username').value = "username""

into the url bar and hit enter it goes to a white page with the text "username".

I would like it to fill the textbox with "username" instead.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the code you want to use in a script file and load this file onto the opened page. Or type the code you're using into the console, not into the URL bar. That bar is for navigating hyperlinks, so as you noticed, if you fill in some javascript code, you'll get a new blank page to run that script.

Comment: @Shilly chrome lets you just type `javascript: alert("hello world")`

Comment: Other browsers might not. Being able to run js that way doesn't help in any way with the OPs problem, unless you make a longish script to stop the redirecting. Which is harder than to just use the console or append a new script to the page you want to run the script on.

Comment: I used chrome and it still sent me to a blank page.

Comment: I used the console and it worked :) Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: I have posted the answer, it work in address bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can add void(0) at the end of the code. Paste this in address bar.

Try this:

```
javascript:document.getElementById("login-username").value="Hello";void(0);
```

Hope this helps.